# Reset the contents of Card view on back pressed button

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have two Activities. Let us suppose its Activity A and Activity B. I have a Recycler view in A, which has multiple card views inside it. There is an Edit Text field called 'Description' in each Card View which only appears when a Radio button field present in the same card view is switched to true, else its hidden. Activity B is a History Activity, which is also a Recycler View having Card View's inside it. Now what's happening is, when I comeback from Activity B to A by pressing back button, that Edit text field which should be hidden, still appears in the Card View. I want to hide it and reset the card view to its normal state. Can anyone help me with this?

Note: I haven't used onBackPressed() anywhere in this. Its going back by default functionality.

Comment: Use `onBackPresses()`, this method always calls when a back button pressed on a activity. So, in this method read your content from the cardview

Comment: That's okay. But my problem doesn't get resolved by that. I want one Edit Text field in the card view to become invisible when we return to that activity after pressing back button on another Activity.

Comment: write some code , then we can give you the solution.

Comment: you can have an interface which would throw callback to your previous activity which will further refresh your card recyclerview, this should be done before super.onBackpressed().

Answer (score 1):

You can save each item's state in your adapter with:

```
 static SparseBooleanArray itemState = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

and when it changes, in ViewHolder:

```
                itemState.put(currentPosition, true);
```

then in onBindViewHolder check your RadioBotton's state and update.